# PostMessage not working for WM_PASTE , mfc

Tags: c++, mfc, postmessage

I have an application which has a button on Click of button am trying to paste the text already available to Notepad. My application gathers the text first and puts it on the clipboard(this is working perfectly fine), I am facing problem with the Paste part. Here is the code, Please let me know where am i going wrong.

```
CWnd *pCwnd = FindWindow(NULL, _T("Untitled - Notepad"));
    HWND handle = pCwnd->GetSafeHwnd();
    pCwnd->PostMessageA(WM_PASTE,0,0);
```

I am using Notepad to test it so the name is ("Untitled -  Notepad").
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use MFC, but you can probably translate to what you need.  The issue is you need to send the message to the edit control, not the main window.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    const std::string data("This is some text from the clipboard.");
    HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, data.size() + 1);
    std::memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), data.c_str(), data.size() + 1);
    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    OpenClipboard(NULL);
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
    CloseClipboard();

    HWND mainWindow = FindWindow(NULL, "Untitled - Notepad");
    HWND editWindow = FindWindowEx(mainWindow, NULL, "edit", NULL);
    PostMessage(editWindow, WM_PASTE, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey extremely thankful for the code. I have been struggling from Morning to get it working.One more question is, In case of browser if I want to do the same then how can i do it. Ex: I Have a webpage open and I have focused on first editbox and go to my application and click button it should paste the text, in the focused text box. Also i have created a function which puts [TAB] in between strings so in that case when [TAB] is encountered it should go to next Edit and paste the string.

Comment: It's really going to depend on the particular application and how they have things set up.  You can use something like Spy++ to try and figure out which window to target but it's often a bit of trial and error.